# Object with wireframe modifier not showing up on render in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

It shows up in Blender Render but not in Cycles, this one object with a Wireframe modifier. Applying the modifier doesn't help, nor does making it thicker. It is set to render in the Outliner. I can't think of what else could be the problem.

[image: screenshot in Blender]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the object enabled for rendering (camera icon)? Is the object in a render layer that is part of the render layers?

Comment: @cegaton yes, rendering enabled, and on a layer that is being rendered.

Comment: look through the answers on this post and if none work in your case please make the file available https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Comment: Is the ray visibility enabled for camera?

Comment: Is the object not visible for render only with Wireframe modifier or with or without any modifier?

Comment: Ray visibility? That one i can't find...

Comment: @MrZak Actually, not even with the modifier applied, so maybe that isn't even relevant. But it is on the same layer as everything else, so i don't know what else about it is different.

Comment: @cegaton oh - there's ray visibility... Yes, it's enabled.

Comment: I added the file to the question, as it doesn't seem to be any of the issues in the linked answers. (Thanks for that, though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the object visible on the render you need to turn Duplication to None.Otherwise you will see only children of this object duplicated based on set value[image]

Comment: You are my hero for the next few hours.